# Catching ffmpeg errors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, ffmpeg

Currently I make extensive use of tensorflow's ffmpeg interface:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import audio_ops as contrib_audio
from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops
from tensorflow.contrib import ffmpeg

def load(mp3_path):
    with tf.name_scope("loading") as scope:
        audio_binary = tf.read_file(mp3_path)
        waveform = tf.reshape(ffmpeg.decode_audio(
            audio_binary, file_format='mp3', 
            samples_per_second=44100, channel_count=1), [-1])
        return waveform
```

This is wonderful, but sometimes (well, a lot) I get errors like this when looping through a bunch of files to create TFRecord files:

```
[mp3 @ 0xdd4400] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0xf2e440] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0x202bf40] invalid new backstep -1
[mp3 @ 0x15c5440] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0x1752460] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0x1f10160] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0x1a16dc0] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mp3 @ 0x9f2c80] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
```

which shows up in stdout while running this Python script.

I'd like to catch these somehow! And prevent the rest of my loop from continuing if the data I'm reading is invalid.

Currently, these errors just happen and the script happily keeps running, which is probably not the way it should work.

I'm not making use of the Dataset API for this, so these direct `session.run(waveform_op)` calls should throw and Exception or something when parsing fails!

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/ffmpeg/decode_audio) `contrib.ffmpeg.decode_audio` returns an empty tensor if the decoding fails, so you have a way to check if `FFmpeg` encountered a *fatal* error.

This will not work however if the errors are recoverable, since `FFmpeg` will be able to to continue decoding.

Comment: Does "empty" mean full of zeros? How does one detect an empty tensor?

Comment: just to be pedantic - the shape of an empty tensor is what?

Comment: @lollercoaster it's supposed to return a rank-2 tensor so I imagine it'll be `[None, None]` since there's no sample/channels data. Will confirm later.